# Limitations of K-Means Clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I was going through a document of Western Michigan University to understand the limitations of K-means clustering algorithms. Below is the link:

https://cs.wmich.edu/alfuqaha/summer14/cs6530/lectures/ClusteringAnalysis.pdf

On slide no 33 its mentioned that K-means has problems when clusters are of different

- Sizes
- Densities
- Non globular shapes

Since we explore our data and try to figure out the different groups that are present in our data through the k-means clustering algorithm, how would we know that the size of the clusters is different beforehand? We can visualize it if we have two-dimensional data but how it can be done if the data is n-dimensional? Is there any way to examine the data before proceeding to apply k-means.

Also, the explanation for the limitation is: if we have different sizes of clusters, k-means will not give the desirable clusters as it tries to partition the clusters equally. But I don't think its always the case. I had applied k-means on the following dataset with k-means++ initialization

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/online+retail

It gave me clusters with highly uneven distribution of 4346, 23, 3
I think I am missing some prerequisite steps before proceeding. Please help me clear my doubts. Thanks.

Comment: Good question, but better suited for the cross validated stackexchange
https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

That's a limit of k-means. You don't really have a hard fact if your clustering is good or not.

Pre-steps could be:

- Normalization/Standardization of the data with [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)
- Missing value handling
- Dimension reduction (there are several techniques like: PCA), especially if you have a lot of dimensions
- Random initialization (it can vary from the start point)

A real method how good your k-means clustering is doesn't really exists, here is a topic about how to "measure" it: [Clustering Quality Measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6252/clustering-quality-measure)